# Why does JS assume string date without time is UTC if 0 padded and local if not padded?

Tags: javascript, java, date, localdate

This is a bizarre but I'm sure there's a perfectly good explanation.

My team and I recently discovered when using **java's LocalDate** and sending it back to the frontend with the default string format **"YYYY-MM-DD"**, Javascript will automatically create a date assuming that the string was UTC, so living in ET zone, it automatically subtracts -5 hours.

Annoying, but we get it.

However, when we send it back with time as so **"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"**, it parses it as a local date. Ok, weird... but it gets weirder.

Now the bizarre part, if we send the string without the 0 padding on the date as so **"YYYY-MM-D"** it parses it as a local date. **Why?**

Here's an example:

```js
new Date("2017-12-09")
// output: Fri Dec 08 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
new Date("2017-12-9")
// output: Sat Dec 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Why is this???

Comment: In some browsers, `new Date("2017-12-9")` produces an invalid date. Parsing of non–standard strings (i.e. anything not supported by [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.parse)) is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer relies on your browser implementation.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Comment: And ISO 8601 requires padding, so `2017-12-09` is ISO 8601 while `2017-12-9` isn’t. So your quote seems to explain.

Comment: Is there any reason why? I don't understand why they would treat date only and datetime strings differently.

Comment: Well, Javascript is an "old" language that went through a lot of changes and battles between implementations (looking at you, IE). Javascript has been known to be a language with questionnable designing choices. This explain why, as developers, we often use librairies to abstract theses strange choices. (If you want to learn more about JS history, I suggest: https://auth0.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-javascript/)

Comment: Cool! Thanks! I usually use momentjs, so I'm not used to running into these date curiosities.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, check out `date-fns` too, that's a good lightweight alternative to moment